# Date object locale issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, locale

I retrieved a Date object from a plugin's returning value, which is demonstrated as below:

```
$log.info($scope.tm.startDate.toLocaleDateString());
$log.info($scope.tm.startDate);
```

The output is:

```
2     611652   info     August 26, 2016
3     611652   info     2016-08-25T22:00:00.000Z
```

2016-08-26 is expected, but I don't know why it would print something like 2016-08-25T22:00:00. Could anyone tell me how to convert to the desired Date object? Thanks.

Comment: The format used by `.toLocaleDateString()` depends on your locale. If you want a specific format, you should explicitly specify the locale to use. Like: `.toLocaleDateString("en-US")`. Or you can just use the `Date` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this...

```
var date = new Date($scope.tm.startDate);
console.log(date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate());
```

Comment: yes, and it's not worked. Its a number less than 0 when invoking `getTime()` in terms of timestamp. and the only way to get it right is by `toLocaleDateString` or `toLocaleTimeString`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for managing date objects. Much easier and reliable than any manuel manipulation you do by yourself.

You can use its [`.format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method.

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```